# Pattern match sum of terms

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to define a replacement rule for an arbitrary sum of terms in an equation, that returns the x[i] terms along with their coefficients. For example,

```
eqns = {0 == x[1] + y[2], 
         0 == 1 - 8 x[5], 
         0 == 1 + 2 x[3] + 4 y[2] + 3 x[1]}
```

Here's the pattern I tried using

```
patt = (0 == Plus[Optional[a__], Optional[b_]x[c_], Optional[d__]]])

eqns /. pattern :> b * x[c]
```

but this outputs

```
{x[1], - 8 x[5], 3 x[1]}
```

the output I want is something like

```
{x[1], - 8 x[5], {2 x[3], 3 x[1]}}
```

For some reason it's defaulting to the 3x[1] replacement instead of the 2x[3] replacement. Is there a way to design a replacement rule that spits out all matches in the expression?

( I would prefer it if it could be written in in the form

```
eqns /. pattern :> something
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your replacement returns only one term because only one term is specified in the pattern. Compare

```
x[1] + x[2] /. Plus[Optional[a__], Optional[b_] x[c_], Optional[d__]] :> x[c]
(*x[1]*)
```

and

```
x[1] + x[2] /. Plus[Optional[a__], Optional[b_] x[c_], Optional[b1_] x[c1_],   Optional[d__]] :> {b x[c], b1 x[c1]}
(*{x[1], x[2]}*)
```

Of course, such an approach will not work when you don't know how many terms there will be in the expression. For such cases, there is `Repeated` pattern that stands for a sequence of any number of terms:

```
eqns /. (0 == Plus[seq : Repeated[_. _x], ___] :> {seq})
(*{{x[1]}, {-8 x[5]}, {3 x[1], 2 x[3]}}*)
```

I also strongly recommend not using patterns `Optional[__]` anywhere. `__` stands for *one* or more expressions, which means that MMA will try to populate this patterns at least by one expression **first** and only **if it fails**, MMA will use `Default`. An example:

```
x[1] + x[2] /. Plus[Optional[a__], Longest[seq : Repeated[_. _x]],    Optional[d__]] :> {{seq}, a, d}
(*{{x[1]}, x[2], 0}*)
```

Note that even using `Longest` does not help here. Further, there is no need to use `Optional` at all in your example because your can just use `BlankNullSequence`, which stands for *zero* or more expressions. Finally, `Plus` is `Orderless`, which means that you don't need to care about order of the terms inside `Plus`.

```
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] /. Plus[x[1], x[3], ___] -> True
(*True*)
```

In fact, this is the reason why `Repeated` worked in the example above, because `Repeated` stands for a sequence of expressions which come one after another.